# Loop over type object to check for undefined properties and assigning it to another class object with same fields

Tags: typescript

I have a type that comes from my frontend and a class that I use for my database.

The class I am using for the database:

```
@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class Task {
  @Field(() => Int)
  @PrimaryKey()
  id!: number;

  @Field(() => String)
  @Property({ type: 'date' })
  createdAt = new Date();

  @Field(() => String)
  @Property({ type: 'date', onUpdate: () => new Date() })
  updatedAt = new Date();

  @Field()
  @Property({ type: 'text' })
  name!: string;

  @Field(() => String)
  @Property({ type: 'date' })
  alertAt = new Date();

  @Field(() => Date)
  @Property({ type: TimeType})
  from: TimeType;

  @Field(() => Date)
  @Property({ type: TimeType})
  to: TimeType;

  @Field(() => Boolean)
  @Property({ type: 'boolean' })
  isDaily: boolean;
}
```

The type from my frontend:

```
type TaskInput = {
  id: number,
  from: Date,
  to: Date,
  daily: boolean,
  alertAt: Date
}
```

Then I am trying to loop the TaskInput and assign any field that is not undefined:

```
async updateTask(taskInput: TaskInput)
    const task = await em.findOneOrFail(Task, { id: taskInput.id })

    Object.entries(taskInput).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        if(value){
            task[key] = value;
        }
    })
}
```

But it gives me:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Task'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Task'.

What is the way to handle this?

Comment: Please make a [PlaygroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) link

Comment: @OlegValter I changed it to typeof after I asked the question, but thanks for the warning!

Comment: @ivaylo no worries, just a quick note as somebody was going to ask you sooner or later :) I suggest you edit the question a little to reflect that to avoid being unnecessarily pinged in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this for example:

```
function updateValues<K extends string,A extends {[key in K]:any}>(obj:A, key: K, value:any)
{
  if(value)
    obj[key]=value;
}

Object.entries(taskInput).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      updateValues(task,key,value)
})
```

Comment: Thanks, why not casting it directly in the params of the function updateValues(task : {[key: string]:any})?

Comment: You can cast it to `[key: string]:any` if you prefer, but your type doesn't implement indexer, so it you'll be casting `task` to something that it is not, while using generics does not make any false claims about the type